# Category URL incorrect in Telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

The category URL in telescope should be eg: www.domainname.com/category/sports
Instead in my app it is showing as www.domainname.com/domainname.comcategory/sports
I am not sure which config file or root url is incorrect or is it something else.
Here is my env config

```
// Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://bollymojo.com",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://admin:Affable14@c944.candidate.16.mongolayer.com:10944,c922.candidate.35.mongolayer.com:10922/bollymojo?replicaSet=set-550b97a8fa82e80ceb000438"
  },
```

Could you guys please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a `siteUrl` setting in the Settings panel that overrides `ROOT_URL`. Maybe that's the one you need to set?